# Can I log my users in to multiple services with OAuth?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I have an application that wants to be tied to multiple services, and I'm not sure how to handle the login. Can I have the log in once, suppose through facebook, and grant our application access to twitter?

Can I otherwise store some sort of login credentials on the server side, have the log in to my service, and log them into both server side?

Full disclosure: I'm very fuzzy on how authentication works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users will need to authenticate against and authorize your application for each service.

If you want them to connect via Facebook and twitter you'd need to go through the oauth flow for each one.  After the oauth process is complete you will have access tokens for each of the services which you can use for subsequent requests.

Depending on your language or platform, there may be a library to help you manage your user auth and credentials.  For instance django-social-auth works great for django platforms.